# MODX как правильно написать условие where?

Tags: modx

```
[[!pdoResources?
    &where=`{ "mseIntro.intro:LIKE":"% Слово %" AND "template":"8"}`
]]
```

Как правильно прописать условие, если мне нужно отсортировать ресурсы по слову и по шаблону? Или по слову, шаблону и родителю (3 условия)?

**Upd**

```
[[!pdoResources?
    &loadModels=`msearch2`
    &class=`mseIntro`
    &innerJoin=`{ "Resource":{ "class":"modResource" } }`
    &select=`{ "Resource":"*" }`
    &where=`{ "mseIntro.intro:LIKE":"% Слово %","template":"3" }`
    &sortby=`{ "pagetitle":"asc" }`
    &tplWrapper=`tpl.outer`
    &tpl=`@INLINE <li>[[+pagetitle]]</li>`
    &limit=`0`
]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[[!pdoResources?
&where=`{"mseIntro.intro:LIKE":"% Слово %","template":"8", "parent":"2"}`
]]

> mseIntro.intro

если вы используете кастомную таблицу, нужно конечно в pdoResources это также указать.

Comment: Я добавил полный вызов pdoResources, который использую. Вариант условий через запятую не работает. Если я убираю template=3, ресурсы нормально находятся.